# LNK 1104 Error in C++ Program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-7-x64

I am a .NET Developer who migrated to Visual C++ recently. I had earlier developed some small applications in Visual C++ 6.0. I tried to create a Simple "hello World" console Application using Visual Studio 2012 where I followed the steps mentioned in MSDN. But when I build the Project I get the following Error with the Output displaying me like this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TestApp, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Simple.cpp
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Debug\Simple.obj'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have created an Empty project, added a Simple Cpp file and build it.

This is a very simple App, Dont know if I need to do some settings for VS 2012 running on Windows 7 64 bit OS.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at this MSDN page: [Linker Tools Error LNK1104](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts7eyw4s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Did you have any compiler errors that prevented `Simple.obj` from creating? Is `Simple.cpp` blank?

Comment: No sir, it has a cout statement to display hello world.